# Partial Search text with space in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to search a text with space and partial matching in elasticsearch. I created the field as non_analysed but its working for full text match only (With term):

```
POST /customertype/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "customerTypeName.untouched": "New customer"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I search a text partially (e.g. "New Cust") with space in elasticsearch.

Comment: In your mapping, you've defined a multifield `customerTypeName` untouched (not analyzed) and touched (analyzed) mapping? What is your analyzer(s) for the analyzed field?

Comment: You really should post your mapping and index settings when asking a question!

Comment: Have a read of this if you don't fully understand ES - http://goo.gl/OSWjWs

Comment: Sorry for not posting the mapping..my problem got resolved by using prefix instead of term..